Google authenticator is not recognizing the key while Microsoft authenticator scans successfully and return the code
I created a QR Code using QRCoders and OTP.Net. When I get the secret key and my function generate the qr code the google authenticator says that the key is not recognize while the Microsoft authenticator generates the code for the same qr code.
My code is as follows - the helper class:
namespace TotpApplication.Service 
{
    public class TotpHelper 
    {
        public static string GenerateSecretKey() 
        {
            var key = KeyGeneration.GenerateRandomKey(20);
            return Base32Encoding.ToString(key);
        }

        public static string GenerateQrCodeUri(string secretKey, string account, string issuer)
        {
            return $"otpauth://totp/{issuer}:{account}?secret={secretKey}&issuer={issuer}&digits=6";
        }

        public static byte[] GenerateQrCode(string uri)
        {
            using var qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            var qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(uri, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);

            using PngByteQRCode qrCode = new(qrCodeData);
            byte[] qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(5);

            return qrCodeImage;

            // using (var qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
            // {
            //    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            //    {
            //        qrCodeImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            //        return ms.ToArray();
            //    }
            // }
        }

        public static bool ValidateTotp(string secretKey, string code)
        {
            var totp = new Totp(Base32Encoding.ToBytes(secretKey));
            return totp.VerifyTotp(code, out long timeStepMatched, new VerificationWindow(2, 2));
        }
    }
}

ASP.NET Core MVC controller (controller with views):
namespace TotpApplication.Controllers
{
    public class TotpController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Setup(string secretKey, string userId, string issuer)
        {
            var uri = TotpHelper.GenerateQrCodeUri(secretKey, userId, issuer);
            var qrCodeImage = TotpHelper.GenerateQrCode(uri);
            ViewBag.QrCodeImage = Convert.ToBase64String(qrCodeImage);
            return View();
        }
    }
}

API controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TotpApplication.Service;

namespace TotpApplication.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ApiRequestsController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ApiRequestsController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetSecretKey()
        {
            string secretKey = TotpHelper.GenerateSecretKey();
            
            string result = "Your secret key is: " + secretKey;
            return Ok(result);
        }

        // GET api/<ApiRequestsController>
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(string code, string secretKey)
        {
            if(TotpHelper.ValidateTotp(secretKey, code))
            {
                return Ok(true);
            }else
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid Code. Please try again");
            }
        }
    }
}

Setup view:
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TOTP Setup";
}

<h2>TOTP Setup</h2>

<p>Scan this QR code with your authenticator app:</p>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@ViewBag.QrCodeImage" alt="QR Code" />

Previously, when I was using ASP.NET Core MVC for the implementation, the Google authenticator was generating the code successfully and since I shifted some code to API requests the Google authenticator stopped worked and keep on saying that the key is not recognized.

I tested with your code but the Google Authenticator can recognize the secret key . I generate the key and reach the code page , scanned with the authenticator app. Am I misunderstanding the issue? Could you please provide more details to avoid the confusion? BTW, check the time synchronization.
